# I want to determine the impact of a policy on carbon emissions in a single country by doing difference in difference but don't have a control group

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, control-group

The policy was implemented all over the country and applies to everyone. Can I do difference in difference looking at yearly total emissions data of the country before the policy was implemented vs after the policy was implemented? without using a control group